# Remove "yak" from a string

Tags: java

I am working on a codingbat problem:Given a string, return a version where all the "yak" are removed, but the "a" can be any char. The "yak" strings will not overlap. I am look at the solution but there is one part of that code I do not understand.....
How come the first part of the if statement "i = i+ 2" could return the string and you don't need anything else? I mean after all these three conditions are met and just write i = i + 2,and that's it. that is going to give you a String as a result. I don't get it, please help.

```
public String stringYak(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    // Look for i starting a "yak" -- advance i in that case
    if (i+2<str.length() && str.charAt(i)=='y' && str.charAt(i+2)=='k') {
      i =  i + 2;
    } else { // Otherwise do the normal append
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: can u make some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is *selecting* what characters to put in the new string.

We go through the characters one by one.

If we run into a "y.k", skip this whole section

Else add the character to the new string.

> [a][b][y][c][k][d] => New String: [a] (a is okay)
>   .|..........................
>
> [a][b][y][c][k][d] => New String: [a][b] (b is okay)
>   ......|.....................
>
> [a][b][y][c][k][d] => New String: [a][b] (Oops! We have run into the y.k
>   pattern, skip it)   ..........|.................
>
> [a][b][y][c][k][d] => New String: [a][b][d] (d is okay)
>   .....................|......
>
> Final String: [a][b][d]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the style of answer you want, but a simple call to [String#replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) should work:

```
String str = "Some string yak containing yok.";
str = str.replaceAll("y.k", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `i = i + 2` is not going to give you any `String` it is simply incrementing the `for` loop so you do not need to re-evaluate the next two `chars` as they have already been evaluated.

The key point is in the `else` part, which will append the `char` if it is not `y` and the character after-next is also not `k`

Comment: Thank you, but how does it remove the y and k, i mean in the first part of the if statement, it only incremented i = i + 2, don't we need to put a line of code like result = result + str.charAt(i) as well. so the program can return a string. the else part is only when all these condition are false, it's executed, right. so they are seperated

Comment: The code is creating a new String, so it is not removing anything, it is simply **not** adding it.  If possible try stepping through this code with a debugger